# ElasticSearch - Match all nested variations in a document

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

I have several products with variations like the one below

```
{
    "title": "100% Cotton Unstitched Suit For Men",
    "slug": "100-cotton-unstitched-suit-for-men",
    "price": 200,
    "sale_price": 0,
    "vendor_id": 32,
    "featured": 0,
    "viewed": 20,
    "stock": 4,
    "sku": "XXX-B",
    "rating": 0,
    "active": 1,
    "vendor_name": "vendor_name",
    "category": [
        "men_fashion",
        "traditional_clothing",
        "unstitched_fabric"
    ],
    "image": "imagename.jpg",
    "variations": [
        {
            "variation_id": "34",
            "stock": 5,
            "price": 200,
            "variation_image": "",
            "sku": "XXX-C",
            "size": "m",
            "color": "red"
        },
        {
            "variation_id": "35",
            "stock": 5,
            "price": 200,
            "variation_image": "",
            "sku": "XXX-D",
            "size": "l",
            "color": "red"
        }
    ]
}
```

I am looking for a query that would have all of the below parameters

1. Get all products in a certain category
2. Get all products that are black
3. Get sizes l and m

**My current Query:**

```
{
    "size": 15,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "category": "women_fashion"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "nested": {
                                "path": "variations",
                                "query": {
                                    "bool": {
                                        "must": [{
                                                "match": {
                                                    "variations.color": "red"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "match": {
                                                    "variations.size": "l"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "match": {
                                                    "variations.size": "m"
                                                }
                                            }
                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It works fine if i only search for 1 size. But once i search for 2 sizes it gives no records. My guess is that it looks for all 3 parameters in every nested variation, which obviously it cant find. How would i modify the query to search for

1. size: m, color: black
2. size: l, color: black

I have also tried using a nested filter, but the issue with this is that it works like "SHOULD" query while i am looking for a "MUST" query. ie. it shows all the products have large variations while i just want to show products that are large and red.

**My Second Query:**

```
{
    "size": 15,
    "from": 0,
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [
                        {
                            "match": {
                                "category": "women_fashion"
                            }
                        },
                        {
                            "nested": {
                                "path": "variations",
                                "query": {
                                    "bool":{
                                        "filter": [
                                            {
                                                "term": {
                                                    "variations.color": "red"
                                                }
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "term": {
                                                    "variations.size": "l"
                                                }
                                            }

                                        ]
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the size variations into a clause of it's own so at least one of the sizes will match

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "category": "women_fashion"
              }
            },
            {
              "nested": {
                "path": "variations",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "match": {
                          "variations.color": "red"
                        }
                      },
                      {
                        "query": {
                          "bool": {
                            "should": [
                              {
                                "match": {
                                  "variations.size": "l"
                                }
                              },
                              {
                                "match": {
                                  "variations.size": "m"
                                }
                              }
                            ]
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```